# Can we connect Tableau tool with Adobe Analytics (Omniture) Server?

Tags: datasource, tableau-api, adobe-analytics

Can we connect Tableau tool with Adobe Analytics fomerly Omniture Server?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct Tableau integration, however Adobe Analytics allows you to export data for use in Tableau.

1. Go to Tools > Data Warehouse
2. Create the export with the settings you want (date range, segment, variables, etc.)
3. Under Delivery, click Advanced Delivery Options
4. Select Tableau Format (TDE) as the filetype

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're referring to a more integrated approached? If that's the case, then no there isn't one. But, you could do a more data extract approach, either through an API or data warehouse.

This would give you an output where you could then do what you wanted to it. The complexity would vary of course, and depending on the type of data you're looking for would definitely determine the type of output.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is no direct Tableau integration, but you can automate the fetching of your Adobe Analytics data by using community built connectors.

Here’s an example of a free one that was launched at the Adobe Un-Summit this year:

1. On Tableau, select the "More..." tab to access the list of connectors
2. Click on "Web Data Connector"
3. In the popup window that appears, click on the URL box in the center of the screen and enter tableau.cognetik.com for the Cognetik web data connector. Hit Enter.

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

(full disclosure, I work for the company that built it, but we’re seeing it used by multiple companies worldwide).